# Why is the intersection of two lines given by this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two lines, $L$ and $L’$ in 3-D. Some notes in projective geometry says that their intersection is given by $ L \times L’$ which is a vector. I understand that if $L$ and $L’$ intersect they form a plane. So does their intersection correspond to the vector perpendicular to this plane?

Comment: Do your lines contain the origin so they can be interpreted as points of the projective plane?

Comment: No, they don’t.